# How to make double border on left only with thick outside and thin inside

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make a double border on the left side only with thick outline (outer) and thin outline (inner). How can I make it?

[image: Double border Image]

Comment: Sorry, you can't do that in MySQL.

Comment: thanks i checked the other duplicate of my question but it make the border all over the content i just want to set this border with thick and thin lines  on the left side of my content

Comment: @Kaveh You can use a pseudo element. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3peo5xd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for..

```css
.border1{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  }
.border2{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 display: block;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div class="border1">
  <div class="border2"></div>
</div>
```

Check it and let me know if you want any thing else..

Comment: thanks so much i really appreciate that

Comment: Glad to help...